Is this new Hardie/Window installation going to leak?
LINK TO PHOTOS
Hardie siding was installed at my house and it doesn't look quite right to my (untrained) eye. I'm concerned that this install cause issues, whether by (a) immediate water issues/leaks or (b) causing the Hardie to prematurely fail.
Essentially, the Hardie trim around the windows was installed on top of Hardie siding planks. Everything is caulked where the windows meet the trim, but not where the trim meets the siding planks.
The contractor is saying it's completely fine and won't cause water leak issues.
Questions:

Is it OK for the trim to overlay the siding at windows?
Is the window flashing + trim installed properly?
Do I need to caulk where the Hardie trim overlays the siding around the windows vertically?
Do I need to caulk where the Hardie trim overlays siding horizontally on the bottom or on top? (My understanding is NOT on top/by the flashing.)
Do I need to caulk where the Hardie trim overlays the siding on the outside corners?
Do you see anything else iffy?

If this is all wrong, is there a way to fix without having to remove the trim, cut the existing siding, and replace the trim so the siding butts up against it?
Any nuance you have have re: "this is improper per Hardie recommendations, but unlikely to cause issues" vs. "this is improper and definitely will cause issues" would be appreciated.
Thanks for your help and input.




You should caulk along the sides and top, as with any window trim. Not the bottom, so any water that does get in can drain out.

You asked this same question a couple of days ago as Ricky, and got an answer.
